# jQuery Mobile Button Icon in Header goes underneath

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

In my header of my page I have to put two button side by side. For ref, see the screen shot below. [image: The actual requirement where the buttons are side by side]

But after using following code, the icons are over lapping each other. For Ref. see the screen shot below.

```
<div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed"> <a data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="a" href="#homepage" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left"> Back </a>
<h3> Header </h3>
<a data-role="button" href="#homepage" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right home_icon_top"></a>
```

[image: One button goes underneath]

I am using jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Then change the CSS style of Menu icon class to show some margin-right.

Comment: @Anup We have already tried that, but it's of no use.

Comment: Will be helpful if you create fiddle to know exactly what is the issue.

Comment: @Debopam does the answer below work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.home_icon_top{
    right:50px !important;
}
```

Adjust the value of the right as your wish.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mXjHJ/397/)